# how to make new home screen launcher in android?

Tags: android

i am trying to make HOME-SCREEN Launcher in android for my application.
So,please give me some  ideas how to develop it and sample for the same.

Thanks in Advance--

Comment: Do you mean a homescreen replacement app or another launcher icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use google every now and then :-)

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html